# SQLITE 3 Not writing to table

Tags: sqlite, ecmascript-6

I am trying to store an array of objects like this.

```
   "id": "EExKKTC8IuL",
    "date": "2019-02-18T14:57:52.997Z",
    "timestamp": "1550500384",
    "title": "Financial Giant SBI Aims to Boost Ripple and Push XRP Ahead of Bitcoin in Crypto Market CapFinancial Giant SBI Aims to Boost Ripple and Push XRP Ahead of Bitcoin in Crypto Market Cap",
    "score": 6,
    "comparative": 0.18181818181818182
```

Into a better-sqlitev3 table. I am usually able to do it with simple id KEY auto increment. But I am trying to keep the ID's of the articles in the db so they dont duplicate. Here is the code.

```
    try {

    const table = "coinna"
    const dbFile = "scraped"
    const dataDir = "./data/"
    const dbExt = ".db"

    const dbConn = db(`${dataDir}${dbFile}${dbExt}`);
    dbConn.prepare("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL").run();
    dbConn
      .prepare(
        `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [${table}] (id PRIMARY KEY, date DATETIME, timestamp INT, title VARCHAR, score DECIMAL, comparative INT)`
      )
      .run();

    const insertStmt = dbConn.prepare(
      `INSERT INTO [${table}] (date, timestamp, title, score, comparative) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`
    );
    dbConn.transaction(() => {
      parsedResults.forEach(
        ({ date, timestamp, title, score, comparative }) =>
          insertStmt.run(
            date, 
            timestamp, 
            title, 
            score, 
            comparative
          )
      );
    })
    console.log(`${parsedResults.length} added to ${table}`);
} 

      catch (e) {
         console.log(e.message);
       }
```

Comment: Why aren't you inserting the id values along with the rest of the data?

Comment: I actually tried that as well and its not working either. I have no clue.

Comment: `dbConn.transaction(() => {
      parsedResults.forEach(
        ({ id, timestamp, title, score, comparative }) =>
          insertStmt.run(
            id,
            timestamp, 
            title, 
            score, 
            comparative
          )
      );`

Answer (score 0):

Issue was I was missing a ();.

Answer below.

```
   try {

    const table = "coinna"
    const dbFile = "scraped"
    const dataDir = "./data/"
    const dbExt = ".db"

    const dbConn = db(`${dataDir}${dbFile}${dbExt}`);
    dbConn.prepare("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL").run();
    dbConn
      .prepare(
        `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [${table}] (id PRIMARY KEY, date DATETIME, timestamp INT, title VARCHAR, score DECIMAL, comparative INT)`
      )
      .run();

    const insertStmt = dbConn.prepare(
      `INSERT INTO [${table}] (date, timestamp, title, score, comparative) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`
    );
    dbConn.transaction(() => {
      parsedResults.forEach(
        ({ date, timestamp, title, score, comparative }) =>
          insertStmt.run(
            date, 
            timestamp, 
            title, 
            score, 
            comparative
          )
      );
    })(); //here is where the (); needed to be.
    console.log(`${parsedResults.length} added to ${table}`);
} 

      catch (e) {
         console.log(e.message);
       }
```